# CKEditor Not displaying textarea content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor version 3.6.4 in my MVC3 Application.

1) I have included both js in my application

```
<script src="../../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2) Below code is my textarea and i am binding viewdata to textarea.

```
<textarea id="txtAreaBody" name="txtAreaBody" rows="15" cols="220"><%= ViewData["Body"]%>    </textarea>
```

3) To call ckeditor , i have written below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $("#txtAreaBody").ckeditor(); </script>
```

That's it.

and i have html content in my Viewdata.

As you can see from below screenshot, when i am running my application , my textarea is blank. and i am not able to see my content.

[image]

Can anyone please help me ..?

Comment: Are you sure that `<%= ViewData["Body"]%>` displays any content at all? Are you sure that `<%= ViewData["Body"]%>` happens **before** CKEditor is initialized? Firstly I'd inspect HTML source and check whether `<textarea>` next to the editor (it is hidden) has some value.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say whether your textarea is in a partial view or full full, if its in a partial view, Viewdata will not work, you would have to use @tempdata, if in full view, try removing ckeditor() and see if textarea is populated with any data.

Hope it helps or points you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Yep, another cause of this is if you use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` instead of `@Html.TextAreaFor()` then CKEditor will not pick it up, and you will see an empty WYSIWYG Editor with no text, despite the data being passed through the model.